# AppInventor 2: resize image (Canvas) proportionally to fill the space

Tags: android, app-inventor

I have `Canvas` with `BackgroundImage` (selected by user) that should fill all available space.

[image]

But if I set Canvas Height/Width to `Fill` it becomes simply stretched non-proportionally.

And with `Automatic` it's too small for some reason, much smaller than the original image (tested in Genymotion emulator and on OnePlus 3T with Android 8, in both screen orientations).

[image]

Is it possible to resize it to max possible size while keeping the aspect ratio?

It would be easy if I could get the image size in blocks, but I don't see any way to do it. I also tried to use Canvas `Width`/`Height` but looks like they are not updated immediately after setting the image (during screen initialization) and I don't see any other events.

Comment: @Taifun yes, that's what I did already in my answer.

Comment: @Taifun btw you linked some closed group that doesn't even accept requests.

Comment: sorry about that, I just removed the link... great that you found the solution using a clock component now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using `Clock` (timer with small interval, such as `100`).

[image]

[image]

It seems to work as expected on the image from my question (1920x1080). However on some images I noticed strange issues with quality, like it was a small image resized to much bigger size (especially noticeable on images containing text) even though it works fine in other viewers. But it's probably not related to this resizing (I even tried to clear and set `BackgroundImage` again after resizing), here is a similar report: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mitappinventortest/_Iro4UKNE1Q

Comment: somehow this looks more difficult than actually programming it.

Comment: @MartinZeitler yeah. I had to use AppInventor just for one assignment in my university.